# How can I get ssh to use a different IdentityFile based on the USER I've chosen?

Tags: ssl, ssh

I've found lots of help showing how to configure .ssh/config to choose an identityFile based on the *hostname* I'm connecting to, but I connect to a large number of hosts, using one of two *usernames*. I want ssh to recognize what username I've selected, and select the matching IdentityFile.

I tried this:

```
Host admin@*
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/admin_id_rsa
Host chintchary@*
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/chintchary_id_rsa
```

using ssh -v I can see that the config is being ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the syntax wrong in few aspects:

- There are no colons `:` between keys and values
- `User` is not part of `Host`, but it can be matched using `Match` block

Your config should look like this:

```
Match user admin
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/admin_id_rsa
Match user chintchary
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/chintchary_id_rsa
```

All of it can be read from your manual page for [`ssh_config(5)`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config). Afterward make sure that your file is read. With your version, it should yell about bad syntax.

## Alternative for older openssh

If your openSSH version doesn't support `Match` blocks, you need to make some ugly hacks using bash functions, something like this one:

```
ssh(){
  expr match "$@" '.*admin@.*' && I="-i ~/.ssh/admin_id_rsa"
  expr match "$@" '.*chintchary@.*' && I="-i ~/.ssh/chintchary_id_rsa"
  /usr/bin/ssh $I $@
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - the colons were in my question, but not in my config file. Unfortunately "Match" gives me a "Bad configuration option" error, so it may be a version difference. I'm on OpenSSH_6.2p2 - and from past experience, getting the IT department to upgrade SSH is a headache.

Comment: version 6.2 is quite old. What system do you use, that you don't have anything more recent? For older versions, it is probably not possible to make it, except if you write some ugly bash functions that would parse it for you.

Comment: Many thanks for your additional information about older versions - unfortunately I can't apply it because many of the ssh connections are being created by a Perl job, and therefore bypassing bash.